# CSS fails after updates in server

Tags: css, image

I have a server connected to my website. I do local changes about css especially for pictures. I added new pictures, their size are very ok in my local server. But when I add them to remote/website server their size is bigger..

I had this problem before, after 5-10 minutes it was solved automatically, so I thought it updates itself. But this time its not solved, what I should do about it?.. any ideas?

Comment: any ideas guys? :/

Comment: Caching issue maybe?

Comment: Ctrl + f5 will clear cache on Chrome and the changes will appear.

Comment: kamil, I think this was the right answer to my silly question. add your answer as a answer and I will prove it. Thank you :)